MacOS Messages sometimes takes a while to show text messages
My MacBook M1 running Sonoma 14.4.1 has Messages linked to my iPhone X running iOS 17.4.1, and they also both sync to iCloud.
When I get a text message (SMS, MMS or iMessage), usually it shows up in Messages on the Mac at the same time as I hear the ding from the iPhone. But occasionally it can take several minutes before the message shows up on the Mac. This is particularly annoying when the message is a 2FA code for a site I'm logging into on the Mac, since I would like to be able to copy and paste into the browser, rather than going to the phone and copying it manually.
It doesn't seem to matter how far apart the devices are. A few minutes ago it happened when the phone was less than a foot from the Mac.
If I type a reply on the Mac that usually triggers it to pick up the missing messages from the phone within a few seconds.
Is there anything I can do to make messages show up on the Mac more reliably?

Whatever the problem is, it has nothing to do with the spatial location of the Mac and iPhone relative to each other.

I don't really know what mechism is used to link them. But if it's Bluetooth the distance would affect connection quality.

Do you have Messages in iCloud enabled?

Yes, see the second line of my question. I have Messages selected in the iOS iCloud settings, and I have "Enable Messages in iCloud" checked on the Mac. I just enabled the latter a couple days ago, hoping it would solve the problem, but it didn't.

Note: Connecting Messages to your iCloud will upload the contents of the messages as well as all image/video file attachments! If you have many gigabytes of such files in texts, it will take some time to sync to iCloud on all your devices, and there will be some lag: "When you first turn on Messages in iCloud, it may take some time for all your messages to appear on each device. You can send and receive messages during this time." Apple Support.

@IconDaemon I'm not talking about old messages appearing, I'm talking about new messages not showing up immediately when I receive them. As far as I can tell, enabling iCloud sync in MacOS Messages has not had any impact on this.
